# Unable to access databases in ElasticPool. How to restart pool or server when azure portal hangs

Tags: azure, sql, pool

We recently had an issue with our Elastic Pool. And has stopped us accessing all databases. The Alert showed Service health errors but has not come back online for over 3 hours.

Is there a way to restart the azure server or individual pools to resolve the issue.